# How to clear the output when I re-click the execute buttom in Python tkinter app

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have made a simple GUI app with Python tkinter package.

The app allows us to input some chemical formula, and then check whether it exists or not.

However, when I used the input multiple times, the historical results were overlapped in the output window. Here is an example.

[image]

The code is also provided as below.

```
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()
root.title('Peak fitting assistant')

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300,  relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Check if the candidate ions make sense')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(200, 25, window=label1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Type the chemical formula:')
label2.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(200, 100, window=label2)

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

def formula_check():
    s = entry1.get()   
    label3 = tk.Label(root, text= s + ' is:',font=('helvetica', 10))
    canvas1.create_window(200, 210, window=label3)

    label4 = tk.Label(root, text= out ,font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold')) ## out is the result, the checking process is not relevant to the error here.
    canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=label4)

button1 = tk.Button(text='Check', command=formula_check, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
button1.pack()
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried to add the sentence below, i.e., destroy the output before the next executation in case of overlapping problem.

```
label3 = tk.Label(root)
label4 = tk.Label(root)

def formula_check():
    global label3, label4
    label3.destory()
    label4.destory()
```

However, it was not working then. I would like to inquiry on how to clear the output when click the "Check" buttom.

Comment: why not just update the existing label using `label.config(text='sometext')` or to remove label from the canvas you can use `canvas.delete(tag/id)`. The id is returned by the `create_window` method.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can just use `.config` to configure the text.

```py
label3 = Label(root, font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))    # Create the label outside the function.
label3.pack()

def formula_check():
    s = entry1.get()
    label3.config(text=s)    # This will change the text of the Label instead of overriding it by a new Label instance.
button1 = tk.Button(text='Check', command=formula_check)
button1.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that u're creating a new canvas windows over the previews one, and because the new one is smaller than the before, u're also seeing the previews one.
One way to correct this is create one canvas windows, tag this windows and update the text in it.

Bellow is the code is creating the windows on lines 19 and 20, and updating at lines 25 and 28:

```
  1 import tkinter as tk
  2 
  3 root= tk.Tk()
  4 root.title('Peak fitting assistant')
  5 
  6 canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300,  relief = 'raised')
  7 canvas1.pack()
  8 
  9 label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Check if the candidate ions make sense')
 10 label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
 11 canvas1.create_window(200, 25, window=label1)
 12 
 13 label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Type the chemical formula:')
 14 label2.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
 15 canvas1.create_window(200, 100, window=label2)
 16 
 17 entry1 = tk.Entry (root)
 18 canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)
 19 canvas1.create_window(198, 210, tags=('some_tag_here'))
 20 canvas1.create_window(200, 230, tags=('other_tag_here'))
 21 
 22 def formula_check():
 23     s = entry1.get()
 24     label3 = tk.Label(root, text= s + ' is:',font=('helvetica', 10))
 25     canvas1.itemconfigure('some_tag_here', window=label3)
 26 
 27     label4 = tk.Label(root, text= out ,font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold')) ## out is the result, the checking process is not relevant to the error here.
 28     canvas1.itemconfigure('other_tag_here', window=label4)
 29 
 30 button1 = tk.Button(text='Check', command=formula_check, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
 31 button1.pack()
 32 canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)
 33 
 34 root.mainloop()
```

PS: The error on line 27 is because u haven't declared the "out" variable.